# How do you return an object within an array.reduce?

Tags: javascript

I'm pretty new to JS and first time on here.

How do you return an object within an array.reduce?

So for example: I want to find the lowest low for a given day's dataset (I'm using a currency API as an interesting data-set to play with). The data I get back is an array of objects. So I was using a reduce to iterate over, day-by-day and find the lowest low.

```
const lowestLow = historialCandlesFloatData.reduce((lowestLow,currentDay) => {
        if(currentDay.l < lowestLow.l){
             return lowestLow = currentDay;
        }else return lowestLow;   
},);
```

That works fine, but I'm also going to need the index of the object returned as the lowest. Now I know you can use index as part of reduce, and I can console.log what index the lowest low is, but I can't figure out how to return it along with the low as an object?

I could just use a forEach, which seems to work fine, but this doesn't seem the best way to do it and id really like to know!

```
const findLow = ()=>{
    let currentDayLow = 2;
    let dataIndex = 0;
    let datavalue = 0;

        historialCandlesFloatData.forEach((day)=>{
            if(day.l < currentDayLow){
                currentDayLow = day.l;
                datavalue = dataIndex;   
            }
            dataIndex ++;   
        });
    return {
        lowestLow: currentDayLow,
        indexValue: datavalue,
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes sorry I spotted that just after posting, and have now fixed, but as you can see not the most elegant way to do it. Your reduce solution is what I was hoping to arrive at.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want anything else/more than a value from the array, you'll benefit from using the second argument of `reduce`: the *initial* value of the accumulator. In this case the accumulator would be the currently "best" index, and so that accumulator initial value could be 0.

NB: instead of `if else` you could use the conditional operator.

```
const lowestIdx = historialCandlesFloatData.reduce((lowestIdx, currentDay, i) => {
    return currentDay.l < historialCandlesFloatData[lowestIdx].l
             ? i
             : lowestIdx;   
}, 0); // Initial index
```

And then with that index you can retrieve the corresponding object

```
const lowest = historialCandlesFloatData[lowestIdx];
```

Comment: you can't return when looking for lowest value

Comment: Ah nice... yes that makes sense, much more elegant. (I also just realised by forEach way of tracking the index does not work anyway). Thank you @trincot

Comment: @YasserCHENIK, I think you mistake the `return` statement for something else. This `return` does not interrupt the loop.

Comment: @YasserCHENIK - The `return` just returns from the callback, whereupon `reduce` calls it again with the next element.

Answer (score 2):

To do that with `reduce`, you'll need to make the "accumulator" you pass around an object with the value and index on it. *(Er, or just return the index then use that to get the element, as [trincot showed](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73182715/157247).)* For instance:

```
const lowestLow = historialCandlesFloatData.reduce((lowestLow, currentDay, index) => {
    return !lowestLow || currentDay.l < lowestLow.entry.l ? { entry: currentDay, index } : lowestLow;
}, null);
```

Live Example:

```js
const historialCandlesFloatData = [{ l: 4 }, { l: 1 }, { l: 3 }, { l: 7 }];

const lowestLow = historialCandlesFloatData.reduce((lowestLow, currentDay, index) => {
    return !lowestLow || currentDay.l < lowestLow.entry.l ? { entry: currentDay, index } : lowestLow;
}, null);

console.log(lowestLow);
```

Alternatively, you could make the accumulator an augmented version of the objects from the array by adding the index to it:

```
const lowestLow = historialCandlesFloatData.reduce((lowestLow, currentDay, index) => {
    return !lowestLow || currentDay.l < lowestLow.l ? { ...currentDay, index } : lowestLow;
}, null);
```

Live Example:

```js
const historialCandlesFloatData = [{ l: 4 }, { l: 1 }, { l: 3 }, { l: 7 }];

const lowestLow = historialCandlesFloatData.reduce((lowestLow, currentDay, index) => {
    return !lowestLow || currentDay.l < lowestLow.l ? { ...currentDay, index } : lowestLow;
}, null);

console.log(lowestLow);
```

---

But I'm not a fan of using `reduce` with ad hoc functions, not least because it's so easy to trip over it by forgetting to provide a seed value (when necessary), forgetting to do a `return` on all code paths, etc. Unless you're doing functional programming with predefined, reusable reducer functions, I much prefer simple loops:

```
let lowestLow = null;
let lowestIndex;
for (let index = 0; index < historialCandlesFloatData.length; ++index) {
    const entry = historialCandlesFloatData[index];
    if (!lowestLow || entry.l < lowestLow.l) {
        lowestLow = entry;
        lowestIndex = index;
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const historialCandlesFloatData = [{ l: 4 }, { l: 1 }, { l: 3 }, { l: 7 }];

let lowestLow = null;
let lowestIndex;
for (let index = 0; index < historialCandlesFloatData.length; ++index) {
    const entry = historialCandlesFloatData[index];
    if (!lowestLow || entry.l < lowestLow.l) {
        lowestLow = entry;
        lowestIndex = index;
    }
}

console.log(lowestLow);
```

Yes, in this case it's more code, but you may find it clearer and/or less error-prone, especially if you're just starting out.

Comment: Thansk for your help, agree normal loops are certainly more what im used to but just trying to get used to some of the various array functions.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add a new property to the object using JavaScript's spread operator `...`? For example, like this:

```js
const lowestLow = historialCandlesFloatData.reduce((lowestLow, currentDay, idx) => {
        if(currentDay.l < lowestLow.l){
             return {
                 ...currentDay,
                 idx: idx,
             };
        } else {
             return lowestLow;
        }  
},
// Initial value
{ l: historialCandlesFloatData[0].l + 1 }
);

// Now you can access the index like so
const index = lowestLow.idx;
```

Comment: @trincot correct, I had just realised this. Your solution is a better one, anyway, but I will update to fix this.

Comment: OK, good now ;-) +1